# How to get column name and column index

Tags: r, dataframe, r-colnames

Hi I have the below dataframe. Since the column contains NA's the datatype of the column is `character`. Now, I need to get the column name and index which only contains String value.

In the example below, I want to get the column name and column index of Zo-A and Zo-B:

```
 ZONE-1        Zo-A         Zone-3        Zo-B
 58            On             75          NA
 60            NA             NA          High
 NA            Off            68          Low
 70            On             NA          NA
```

So far I tried to first convert all of them to numeric, which created NA's for Zo-A and Zo-B column. And if I use the below code for column index, I'm getting NA's as a result

```
a <- which(colnames(df)=="Zo-A" )
integer(0)

match_col <- match(c("Zo-A","Zo-B")names(df))
NA NA
```

I need to perform below operations:

1. I need to first get the `column names` which consists of `String` values
2. I need the `column index` for the same

Comment: The dash is not allowed in colnames so it is converted to `.`, at least when I tried it), try: `which(colnames(df)=="Zo.A")`

Comment: By default it takes dash. And my actual column name is pretty big, with lots of dashes. And the columns I have in my dataset is around 100. So converting them all to ` .`  would be difficult.

Comment: No than that's the issue only by reading the data myself, can you share some input (dput)?

Comment: `a <- which( colnames(JCI_S2_Reshape)=="MUS2-T-H.ZONE-1-T.MUS2-T-H.ZONE-1-T.Present Value (Trend1)" )` this worked though. 
But first I need to find out those column names with string value in it.

Comment: What do you mean by *string-value*? Do you need something like this `grep('\\D+', colnames(d), value = TRUE)` ?

Comment: Works with me, I cannot reproduce your error. The column index returned by `which` is `2`, as expected.

Comment: @timfaber when reading the data in with `read.table`,  use `check.names = FALSE`, and the column names will have the dashes.

Comment: yes, worked for me as well using dots hence I figured it was symbol-related, thanks!

Comment: @Jaap : As I have mentioned in my example, "Zo-A" and "Zo-B" columns consists of values like "On", "Off" etc. where as the other 2 columns have numeric value.  Hence I need to figure out those columns with "string values"

Comment: @RuiBarradas I'm loading the file using "read.csv" 
`df<- read.csv("Mus.csv",header = T, stringsAsFactors=FALSE)`

Comment: When columns have string values they will be automatically forced to *character*-class (when you use `stringsAsFactors=FALSE` in `read.csv`). Hence, `sapply(d, is.character)` will give you a logical vector indicating which columns contain *'string'*-values. To get the name, you can use: `colnames(d)[sapply(d, is.character)]`.

Comment: @Jaap thanks, this lists out all the column names, since it contains "NA" which consider that column as character.
I need those columns, whose values have "On", "Off" etc. As I have explained above in the example as well. 
In the above example, i need to get the colnames of Z0-A and Z0-B.
In my actual dataset, I have more columns around 100, and need to figure out those colnames similarly

Comment: I wonder whether you tried my code, because it gives me exact the columnnames you need.

Comment: Thanks. Again it gives all the character columns. I need only those character columns which has "String value" like on,off, high , low and **not** numerical value like 58,70.
I have clearly mentioned above with an example.

Comment: Reading a `data.frame` from csv with columns containing `NA`, is not affecting the `class` for me. I get the columns 'Zone-1' and 'Zone-3' as `numeric` only. If your data itself contains `NA` as a string "NA" then you can specify that in the read.csv setting this parameter `na.strings = c("NA")`.

Answer (score 4):

For what I understand of your question, what you want or need is really, really simple.

First, read the data in.

```
df <- read.table(text = "
ZONE-1        Zo-A         Zone-3        Zo-B
 58            On             75          NA
 60            NA             NA          High
 NA            Off            68          Low
 70            On             NA          NA
", header = TRUE, check.names = FALSE)

str(df)
'data.frame':   4 obs. of  4 variables:
 $ ZONE-1: int  58 60 NA 70
 $ Zo-A  : Factor w/ 2 levels "Off","On": 2 NA 1 2
 $ Zone-3: int  75 NA 68 NA
 $ Zo-B  : Factor w/ 2 levels "High","Low": NA 1 2 NA

df
  ZONE-1 Zo-A Zone-3 Zo-B
1     58   On     75 <NA>
2     60 <NA>     NA High
3     NA  Off     68  Low
4     70   On     NA <NA>
```

Now, question (1), "first get the column names which consists of String values". All column names consist of string values so this can be done either with `names` or with `colnames`.

```
names(df)
[1] "ZONE-1" "Zo-A"   "Zone-3" "Zo-B" 

colnames(df)
[1] "ZONE-1" "Zo-A"   "Zone-3" "Zo-B"
```

Now question (2), to get the column index of "the same". (I assume it's of column `Zo-A` you are asking for.)

```
a <- which(colnames(df) == "Zo-A")
a
[1] 2

a2 <- grep("Zo-A", colnames(df))
a2
[1] 2
```

**Data in dput format.**

```
df <-
structure(list(`ZONE-1` = c(58L, 60L, NA, 70L), `Zo-A` = structure(c(2L, 
NA, 1L, 2L), .Label = c("Off", "On"), class = "factor"), `Zone-3` = c(75L, 
NA, 68L, NA), `Zo-B` = structure(c(NA, 1L, 2L, NA), .Label = c("High", 
"Low"), class = "factor")), .Names = c("ZONE-1", "Zo-A", "Zone-3", 
"Zo-B"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -4L))
```

**Edit**
If you need to get only the column names composed of alphabetic characters and punctuation marks, you can use the following regular expression.

```
a3 <- grep("^[[:alpha:]|[:punct:]]*$", colnames(df))
a3
[1] 2 4
```

Comment: Thanks. But, this approach doesn't fit my scenario.
**1.** I'm reading the file using read.csv
**2.**  **I need only those column names, which consists of values like "on", "off", etc. Not the columns which consists of numerical values.**
**3.** I have a total of 100 columns, out of which around 50 columns consists of values like "On", "off" etc. Hence would be difficult to follow the above approach to find the column names

Comment: @Anagha If you need only the column names, maybe you should try reading them in with `readLines`. Set argument `n = 1` and it will read at most one line, the first where the column headers are supposed to be. If this works, you will get a character vector of those names, no need for extra work. Then use `which` or `grep` to get the indices of the columns you want.

Comment: No, readLines is not giving the result i need. And would prefer, read.csv

Comment: @Anagha I've just edited my answer, see if the issue can be solved with that final `grep`.

Comment: Sorry, it did not.

Comment: @Anagha What went wrong? Can you make your question more clear then?

Answer (score 1):

To obtain this we can use the code below:

```
K=sapply(df,function(x)any(grepl("\\D+",x)))
 names (df)[K]
    Zo.A Zo.B 

 Which (k)
   Zo.A Zo.B 
     2    4
```

Comment: I need to first figure out the column names, then the index. As I have mentioned earlier, my actual dataset consists around 100 columns, out of which few columns have the alpha values. Hence I need to get that first

Answer (score 1):

While reading the data.frame you can specify 'stringsAsFactors=FALSE' and if your data itself contains NA as a string "NA" then you can specify that in the read.csv setting this parameter na.strings = c("NA")

```
df = read.csv('file.csv',header=T,stringsAsFactors=FALSE,na.strings=c("NA"))
```

Then try:

```
type = sapply(df,class) 
indexes = which(type=='character')
nameofindexes = names(indexes)
```